# Spring Security Configuration with JWT Authentication Causes HTTP 403 Forbidden Error in Postman with Bearer token set

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am developing a Spring Boot application and I am trying to implement some authentication using JWT tokens. I have done everything that I can but for some reason the token that is being generated is not letting me access an endpoint when I try to access it from Postman. I have put the token in the Bearer Token section in the Authorisation for Postman but I am still getting a 403 error

Here is the code I have used in the set up

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests( authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);




        return http.build();
    }

}
```

JWTService:

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${SECRET_KEY}")
    private String secretKey;

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver){
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ){
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return(username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
//        var secretKey = ;
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

}
```

AuthenticationFilter:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> repository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
        var user = User.builder()
                .firstName(request.getFirstName())
                .lastName(request.getLastName())
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                .role(Role.USER)
                .build();


        repository.save(user);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder().token(jwtToken).build();
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        var user = repository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder().token(jwtToken).build();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(
            @RequestBody RegisterRequest request
    ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(
            @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request
    ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.authenticate(request));
    }

}
```

Despite me being able to register a new user and then authenticate the user (returns the jwt token), when I go to but this token that is returned in postman to access another endpoint in the project, I get a 403 Forbidden response. Please is anyone able to help me with this.

Comment: i suggest you read the spring security authorization servers best practices for authenticating browser based applications https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390 you have written a custom login which is usually referred to an `implicit flow` which was deprecated in the oauth2 standard because it has some severe vulnerabilities. You should never hand out JWT tokens directly to browser, they where never designed for this. They were designed for authenticating between microservices in the backend. This is why you have to write all this custom code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed negation `!` in `isTokenValid` method.

instead of

```
username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && isTokenExpired(token)
```

should be

```
username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token)
```